# How can I get the data from the csv-parser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-csv-parse

I want to work with the data from a csv file and I have used csv-parser to do that.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results: any[] = [];

var value = fs.createReadStream('file.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data: any) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
    return results;

  });
```

The parser works well and I get the csv printed, but I want to return the data in the value variable.

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

In your snippet the CSV file read in is pushed to the array `results` already. So you can use that, or if you really prefer to use an array entitled `value`, see the snippet below.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const value = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => value.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: @ReluMorosan Please mark this answer as correct, as it effectively solves your issue.